# Traefik v2 http 404 redirect to external

Tags: docker, traefik

For some time now I can't wrap my head around seemingly simple problem:

How to catch unknown routers and redirect it to external domain without using another reverse proxy (eg nginx as described [here](https://imandrea.me/blog/traefik-custom-404/))?

```
traefik:
    ...
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"

      - "traefik.http.routers.http_catchall.rule=HostRegexp(`{any:.+}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http_catchall.priority=1"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http_catchall.entrypoints=unsecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http_catchall.middlewares=error-catch,https-redirect"

      - "traefik.http.middlewares.error-catch.errors.status=404"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.error-catch.errors.service=error-redirect"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.error-catch.errors.query=/"

      - "traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true"

      # now how to use "error-redirect" service to forward to eg https://google.com
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a [file provider](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/providers/file/) in which you define a service for an external url.

```
http:
  services:
    google:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        - url: http://google.com
```

and assign that service in the middleware like so

```
- "traefik.http.middlewares.error-catch.errors.service=google@file"
```

Comment: Nice, thank you, will try later today

Comment: @Facty did it work?

Comment: So sorry I didn't have time yet. I will return to you once tested

Comment: @flopana how can I put it in dynamic configuration or into `traefik.conf` to catch globally?

Comment: @JacekKrysztofik you can use any provider listed [here](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/providers/overview/). How to enter you configuration depends on which you provider you choose to use.

Comment: @flopana I hate this "manual". It's written as if for the developers of traefik themselves so they don't forget stuff. Examples are all without context. What's "foo" in "foo-prefix"? How can I modify it? Nothing is explained.